# Mysql - Group by and select max value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

**reservas_tanatosalas**
[image]

I have the following query:

```
SELECT r.cod_reserva, MAX(r.hora_fin_utc) FROM reservas_tanatosalas r GROUP BY r.cod_tanatosala
```

**Results:** Is showing the right max value but the wrong `cod_reserva`. Why?

```
cod_reserva  MAX(r.hora_fin_utc)
7           9999999999
6           9999999999
```

**What I want to get?:**

```
cod_reserva  MAX(r.hora_fin_utc)
7           9999999999
8           9999999999
```

## UPDATE

cod_reserva could change to varchar in the future hence is not an option to me use max on it.

Comment: can you show all the columns in picture ?

Comment: The picture show all columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `GROUP BY` for this.  Your query is malformed and won't run in the most recent versions of MySQL (with the default settings) or almost any database.

```
select r.*
from r
where r.hora_fin_utc = (select max(r2.hora_fin_utc)
                        from reservas_tanatosalas r2
                        where r2.cod_tanatosala = r.cod_tanatosala
                       );
```

Think about the problem as a *filtering* problem, not an *aggregation* problem.  You want to filter the data so only the most recent row shows up in the result set.

If performance is an issue, then you want an index on `(cod_tanatosala, hora_fin_utc)`.

This is the your query:

This is the query:

```
SELECT r.cod_reserva, MAX(r.cod_tanatosala) FROM reservas_tanatosalas r
GROUP BY r.cod_tanatosala
HAVING MAX(r.hora_fin_utc)
```

This is saying:

- produce one row for each value of `cod_tanatosala`
- return the maximum value of `cod_tanatosala`
- ERROR HERE:  Don't know what to do with `cod_reserva`.  It is not the argument to an aggregation function or in the `GROUP BY`.

The `HAVING` is simply stating that `MAX(r.hora_fin_utc)` is neither `0` nor `NULL`.  Not very useful.

Comment: What is the reason for not using GROUP BY ?

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh Is there a way to use Group by?

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right 'having' is useless here. I was confuse trying to pick a row after group by. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Ricardo check my answer, I found a work around with group by clause

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping the resultset using a different column, while your select statement refers to a different one. Following should definitely work, please let me know if it doesn't:

```
SELECT 
    r.cod_reserva, MAX(r.hora_fin_utc) 
FROM 
    reservas_tanatosalas r 
GROUP BY 
    r.cod_reserva
HAVING 
    MAX(r.hora_fin_utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same query as yours,

```
SELECT MAX(r.cod_reserva), MAX(r.hora_fin_utc) FROM reservas_tanatosalas r GROUP BY r.cod_tanatosala
```

But I used an aggregate function MAX() on r.cod_reserva as well because without it gives an error "this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by" and I got it working, you can test it with MAX(r.cod_reserva).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in most databases including new version of Mysql this code will issue error as you are grouping by a column that is not part of select. Following query will give you what you are after for the dataset you have shown

```
select (select t.cod_reserva from reservas_tanatosalas t 
        where t.hora_fin_utc = a.max_hora_fin_utc 
        and a.cod_tanatosala = t.cod_tanatosala) cod_reserva, 
        a.max_hora_fin_utc
from (
    SELECT x.cod_tanatosala, MAX(x.hora_fin_utc)max_hora_fin_utc
    FROM reservas_tanatosalas x group by x.cod_tanatosala
)a;
```